# Cron job for restart mysql if too many sleep processes

Tags: mysql, cron

I have several scripts which will run every 10 minutes .
But sometimes the script will not executed properly so end up with a lot of sleep processes.

So I wish to restart mysql every n hours or when there are too many sleep processes , I tried something like
`* * * * * /etc/init.d/mysql restart` (I know it's for every minute , but just an example) but not working.

Or is there any other way to prevent sleep processes?Each of my script might run for 8 minutes if there are many data.So i set up cron job for 10 minutes.

Thank you.

Comment: Restarting the database server can only be a temporary workaround, since it can cause alot of other issues to the scripts involved. My advice: try finding out why those sleeping processes are there and build up in the first place to get to the root of the issue.

Comment: @Bjoern Thanks for your advice.How can I check for the errors?Sleep process is because of too many connection is it?But I'm just using msql_connect.Since my script run with modem so sometimes I'm not sure whether is script or modem problem...

Comment: That depends what kind of script it is, how it is invoked and what exactly it does. Maybe post this within a new SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, as stated by Bjoern above: this should be a **temporary** workaround as it's not so much of a solution.

Your problem is that you're trying to restart your mysql client, rather than the daemon (mysql **d**), try this instead:

```
0 * * * * /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.Yes..I need to look into the problem instead of restart it everytime.Really thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sleep processes are mysql connection in the idle status,
established and still waiting for next query to execute.
Chances are you are using myisam, and your script is doing some heavy write,
thus blocking table for read

However, you should NOT kill the processes in sleep.

The concern on sleep status is it still contribute to connection pool,
and might causing [too many connections error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

**THINGS** you have to do :

- find out the problem on your scripts, and make it work
- or increase the maximum allow connection (palliatives, but work better than restart mysql server)

Here is an article about [sleeping connection](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/02/08/debugging-sleeping-connections-with-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices.Yes you're exactly right,I'm using myisam and script is doing heavy write,somemore the scripts are more than 5.I tried to look for the errors..if a script have too many `if...else if...else...` will it effect the processes?

Comment: `if .. else` is fine, Look for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` sql.

Comment: I'm using `Select from .... LIMIT 0,95` , then `If() {  //process...  ;  //update... }` , and it will repeat for 95 times per 10 minutes.
And I'm using PDO to do the update.If I never include mysql_connect in the script but just PDO connect,it will have connection errors so I have to put both there...

Comment: Can you consolidate with one single UPDATE?

Comment: You mean just update for once after all the processes done? It is a good way,I never think of it,then I can prevent from having too many `UPDATE`.

Comment: Yes, You can process first, store the UPDATE into a BIG sql, then run once. Alternatively, you can take a look on the `REPLACE` :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Using `REPLACE` will avoid from facing too many connections than `UPDATE`?I will read that later, have to go now.And really thanks for all your advises.

Comment: Good morning.So...how if I create another query to update all data after the first query is done within the same script?I tried redirect it to other script just to update database but I just noticed that header function won't work with crontab...